# Qt стили градиентов

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос по QSS.
Есть возможность установки градиентов для виджетов. Градиенты задаются через Qt- шные классы градиентов. Вопрос по синтаксису qss:

```
background: QLinearGradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, 
                            x2: 0, y2: 1, 
                            stop: 0   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                            stop: 0.3 rgba(102, 181, 255, 200), 
                            stop: 1   rgba(102, 181, 255, 255));
```

Создание линейного градиента с вектором 0;1. Данный стиль взят из примера, собственно вопрос, что за stop параметры и в каком диапазоне лежат их значения (0..1 ?), хотелось бы ссылку на документацию, сам я как-то не нашел

Comment: По правде говоря **QSS** всего лишь серое подобие **CSS** по этому надо быть осторожным, множество свойств и настроек там не имеется в с равнении с  **CSS**.

Comment: @timob256, ну как серое) из кроссплатформы на с++ очень даже яркое, но я согласен с вами, многие даже документированные возможности работают не так как ожидаешь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование градиентов, в QSS, описано здесь: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#gradient . К сожалению, это вся документация по градиентам.

Да, значения координаты stop должны лежать на отрезке [0., 1.], как это указано в http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgradient.html#setStops

Comment: Да, эту доку я видел, думал есть что-то большее, Спасибо за ответ.