# Как в Qt5 сделать в графическом интерфейсе разные цвета у кнопок?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui

Я только недавно обратил внимание, что в Qt прямо из настройки графического интерфейса программы (В дизайнере хар-ка MainWindow - pallet), можно менять цвет кнопок.

Я нажал на MainWindow чтобы изменить цвета кнопок в программе (у кнопок характеристика pallet - унаследованная), изменил например на фиолетовый,  скомпилировал - при запуске оно не поменяло (при чем я до этого менял, у меня цвет кнопок менялся, хз что потом произошло), я очищал проект, пересобирал - не помогло.

Очень хотелось бы кастомизировать свое приложение именно меняя эти настройки, как мне сделать так чтобы цвет кнопок все таки менялся?[image: Попытка поменять]

Comment: Для этих целей обычно используется qss - он позволяет избежать ручного раскрашивания элементов. Не знаю, как работает дизайнер в данном случае, но, вероятно, вы поставили какой-то флаг, мешающий применению палитры. Картинка похожа на `setEnabled(false)`, поищите, не меняли ли вы это свойство.

Answer (score 1):

Собрал проект с кнопкой и изменил палитру с свойствах кнопки. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите не чего не заработало ;_;

Попробуем через **QSS** :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;"
                                    "color:rgba(255,255,255,255);"
                                    "border-radius: 8px;"
                                    "border-width: 3px;"
                                    "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                    "background-position: top left;"
                                    "background-origin: content;"
                                    "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 110, 100, 200), stop:1 rgba(130, 148, 130, 200));}"
                                    "QPushButton::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}"
                                    "QPushButton{border-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(255, 200, 200, 200));}"
                                    );
}
```

:3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*И да в основном **QSS** [не простой инструмент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888267/qt-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) и и это будет все таки дольше чем настроить характеристики элементов в дизайнере.*

---

Придется расписать всё, как она будет выглядеть при нажатии, отжатии и наведения на неё мышки. Если вы конечно хотите чтобы не уменьшился оптический функционал элемента QPushButton.

Answer (score 0):

В дизайнере ПКМ на QPushButton, выбрать "Change styleSheet", затем "Add color"/"background-color"